# How to customize 'recurrance' of' wp_schedule_event'?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, email, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I am new to WordPress development. I build a function to send email twice a day with [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event). My recurrance is `twicedaily`. Is this possible to change twicedaily time to 9:00 and 14:00. If so how to achieve it? or is there other option to invoke certain event with my customized time?

Answer (score 0):

The code to schedule a cron event takes a timestamp as the first parameter. As long as you set the original timestamp to be 9:00 (on any day) the twicedaily trigger should take care of the rest

```
wp_schedule_event( $timestamp, $recurrence, $hook, $args )
```